# how to set the flow control of serial port?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I  have a `SerialPort` with a setup with flow control to be 1. How to set it in c#. 
I have newline `char` in my port setup and I assume that different to the flow control. My port setup so far is as below. Can anyone help me with setting the flow control please ? Thank you.

```
SerialPort _comm = new SerialPort
{
    PortName = string.Concat("COM", comPort),
    BaudRate = 9600,
    Parity = Parity.None,
    DataBits = 8,
    StopBits = StopBits.One,
    ReadTimeout = 1000,
    WriteTimeout = 5000,
    NewLine = "\r"
};
```

Comment: More than 1 kind of flow control, Handshake.RequestToSend is almost always the correct one.

Comment: Here for this device, for the  port  setting it specifies to be 1. So should I not use handshake.XonXoff  ? Just asking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.handshake(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use Handshake for that to control flow control

Comment: what does the setting 1 used for ? is it ,Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff ?

Comment: None = 0, XOnXOff = 1, RequestToSend = 2, RequestToSendXOnXOff = 3

Answer (score 2):

In myproject I used below code for serial port initialization.

```
public void Serial_Port_Initialize(SerialPort port)
{
        //Initializing the serial port
        port.PortName = port.PortName;
        port.BaudRate = port.BaudRate;
        port.Parity = Parity.None;
        port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        port.DataBits = 8;
        port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        port.RtsEnable = true;
        port.ReadTimeout = 250;
        port.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
}
```